# Attach the user in session to the current EntityManager when writing functional tests

Tags: symfony, testing, doctrine-orm, functional-testing

I'm writing a functional test for an `Action` entity having a relationship with the `User` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Class Action
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\AppBundle\Repository\ActionRepository")
 */
class Action
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="actions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $createdBy;
}
```

User:

```
namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Action", mappedBy="createdBy")
     */
    private $actions;
}
```

And the user is setted in the controller with the following snippet:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ApiBundle\Controller;

/**
 *
 * @Route("/actions")
 */
class ActionController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function postAction(Request $request)
    {
        $action = new Action();
        $action->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());

        return $this->processForm($action, $request->request->all(), Request::METHOD_POST);
    }
}
```

When calling the action with a REST client for example, everything works fine, the relationship between `Action` and `User` is persisted correctly.

Now, when testing the action with a functional test, the relationship is not working because of the following error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Action#createdBy' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: test. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

For my functional test I need to inject a JWT and a session token because my routes are secured by a JWT and I need to have a user in session.

Here is how I inject that:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ApiBundle\Tests;

class ApiWebTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var ReferenceRepository
     */
    protected $fixturesRepo;

    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    protected $authClient;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $fixtures = [];

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $fixtures = array_merge([
            'Acme\AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData'
        ], $this->fixtures);

        $this->fixturesRepo = $this->loadFixtures($fixtures)->getReferenceRepository();

        $this->authClient = $this->createAuthenticatedClient();
    }

    /**
     * Create a client with a default Authorization header.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client
     */
    protected function createAuthenticatedClient()
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->fixturesRepo->getReference('user-1');

        $jwtManager = $this->getContainer()->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager');
        $token = $jwtManager->create($user);

        $this->loginAs($user, 'api');

        $client = static::makeClient([], [
            'AUTHENTICATION' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
        ]);

        $client->disableReboot();

        return $client;
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is that the injected `UsernamePasswordToken` contains a `User` instance which is detached from the current `EntityManager`, thus resulting in the Doctrine error above.

I could merge the `$user` object in the `postAction` method into the `EntityManager` but I don't want to do that because it means I modify my working code to make a test passes.
I've also tried directling merging the `$user` object in my test into the `EntityManager` like this:

```
$em = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$em->merge($user);
```

But it's not working either.

So now, I'm stuck, I really don't know what to do except that I need to attach the user in session back to the current `EntityManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting indicates that the EntityManager contained in the test client's container doesn't know about your User entity. This leads me to believe that the way you are retrieving the User in your `createAuthenticatedClient` method is using a different EntityManager.

I suggest you try to use the test kernel's EntityManager to retrieve the User entity instead. You can get it from the test client's container, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your tweet, I come to complete the given answer and (try to) propose a solution,

The problem is that your user is not managed by the EntityManager, and more simply, because it's not a real existing user that is registered in database.

To get around this problem, you need to have a real (managed) user that doctrine could use for the association that your action is trying to create.

So, you can either create this user at each execution of your functional test case (and delete it when finished), or create it only once when execute the test case for the first time on a new environment.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
/** @var EntityManager */
private $em;

/**
 */
public function setUp()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $this->em = $client->getKernel()
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine');

    $this->authClient = $this->createAuthenticatedClient();
}

/**
 */
protected function createAuthenticatedClient()
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->em
        ->getRepository('Acme\AppBundle\Entity\User')
        ->findOneBy([], ['id' => DESC]; // Fetch the last created

    // ...        

    return $client;
}
```

That's a pity for your fixtures (that are so much sexier), but I don't see any way to attach your fixture as a real entry, as you can't interact more with the tested controller.

Another way would be to create a request to your login endpoint, but it would be even more ugly.

Comment: You're right and @adsc too. The reason I accepted his answer is because it was made a day earlier solved my issue, even if you're is better. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem @DevAntoine. I'm not sure to understand the way adsc give. Did you get around the issue by fetching a real user (not a fixture)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the client's container to fetch the user loaded from the fixture.